# Use of TfidfVectorizer on dataframe

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pandas

I have the dataframe which has two colums(Reviews and Label):

```
  Reviews                                     Label  
0 [cameron, diaz, woman, marri, judg, play]   1  
1 [turgid, dialogu, feebl, character, harvey] 0  
2 [misfortun, watch, rubbish, sky, cinema]    1
```

I want to apply the TfidfVectorizer on the DF.
I have written the following code.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer  
df_x=train_df["Reviews"]  
df_y=train_df["Label"]  
cv = TfidfVectorizer()   
df_xcv = cv.fit_transform(df_x)  
a=df_xcv.toarray()  
cv.get_feature_names()
```

which is giving an error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Why is this throwing an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reviews column is a column of lists, and not text. Tfidf Vectorizer works on text. I see that your reviews column is just a list of relevant polarity defining adjectives. A simple workaround is:

```
df['Reviews']=[" ".join(review) for review in df['Reviews'].values]
```

And then run the vectorizer again. That will fix the problem.

Comment: thanks its working fine. but now its giving an error array is too big; as my data set has 25000 records. how i can remove this error with out  compromising on data frame

Comment: Paste the traceback.

Comment: @ Himanshu Rai                                                                         
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4f3a2ce0230c> in <module>()
      5 cv = TfidfVectorizer()
      6 df_xcv = cv.fit_transform(df_x)
----> 7 a=df_xcv.toarray()
      8 cv.get_feature_names()

Comment: Hard to read this. Which line is throwing error?

Comment: a=df_xcv.toarray()  at this line. @Himanshu Rai

Comment: Did you try restarting your ipython kernel and doing it. Mainly when you are working with limited RAM and if you save some large vectors then you run out of memory. So try restarting your kernel running it. If the error persists. Then either you will have to free some memory or try to create a smaller array. The easiest way would be to remove irrelevant underrepresented words, that will reduce the error significantly without causing much loss. If you havent removed stopwords, do that.

Comment: I removed the toarray()  and now its working. thnaks @Himanshu Rai

Comment: Did you not need the array representation?

Comment: actually I am doing sentiment analysis . so I may need that in future. I don't have clear idea right now.  As I am doing sentiment analysis for the first time

Comment: You will need the array representation. Dont erase the array.  Try the other methods that I suggested.

Comment: I restarted the the kernel and removed the stopwords also. still its giving same error. how to free the memory or create the smaller array?

Comment: Remove irrelevant words. You can check frequency and can select 1000 most frequent and 1000 least frequent, and then optimize the model depending on yout results. Also further data processing such as stemming, lemmatization will reduce the vocabulary significantly. If you have a lot of samples try working with a smaller set.